# Need to create a Table of Contents that expands

Tags: javascript, menu, tableofcontents

I am a beginner at programming and have been assigned a project for my class. I need to create a table of contents for a script.  there must be "back-linking". I have this part, but when I tried to do the second part: make the Acts expandable to see the chapters, which are the links, I am running into trouble.  I do not have any javascrript knowledge and do nt know where to go from here... this is what I have so far:

```
<dl>
     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act One</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc1" id="chapter1">Chapter I - Subservient Twilight</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc39" id="chapter39">Chapter II - Cat Handler</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc151" id="chapter151">Chapter III - Tutorial</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc172" id="chapter172">Chapter IV - Journey Into Faron Woods</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc207" id="chapter207">Chapter V - Faron Descends In to Twilight</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Two</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc272" id="chapter272">Chapter I - The World of Ruin</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc306" id="chapter306">Chapter II - Sword and Shield</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc357" id="chapter357">Chapter III - Chosen Hero of the Gods</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc398" id="chapter398">Chapter IV - The Forest Temple</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Three</span><dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc429" id="chapter429">Chapter I - Servant of Twilight</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc444" id="chapter444">Chapter II - Forgotten Hero</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc500" id="chapter500">Chapter III - Sumo Wrestling</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc607" id="chapter607">Chapter IV - The Passage Into Death Mountain</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc721" id="chapter721">Chapter V - Goron Mines</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Four</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc775" id="chapter775">Chapter I - Castle Under Siege</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc814" id="chapter814">Chapter II - Serenade of Water</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc861" id="chapter861">Chapter III - Under the Great Bridge of Hylia</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc896" id="chapter896">Chapter IV - Flight to Kakariko</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1009" id="chapter1009">Chapter V - Lakebed Temple</a></li></ul></dd>

        <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Five</span><dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc1044" id="chapter1044">Chapter I - Midna's Desperate Hour</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1115" id="chapter1115">Chapter II - The Blade of Evil's Bane</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1120" id="chapter1120">Chapter III - Mirage of the Ancient Gerudo</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1176" id="chapter1176">Chapter IV - Arbiter's Grounds</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Six</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1211" id="chapter1211">Chapter I - Yetis and Soup</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1288" id="chapter1288">Chapter II - Snowpeak Ruins</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1309" id="chapter1309">Chapter III - Temple of Time</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Seven</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc1337" id="chapter1337">Chapter I - Fractured Memories</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1466" id="chapter1466">Chapter II - Hidden Village of the Shadow Tribe</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1523" id="chapter1523">Chapter III - Cannon Ride to the Stars</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1549" id="chapter1549">Chapter IV - City in the Sky</a></li></ul></dd>

     <dt><span onclick="showHide(this)">Act Eight</span></dt>
           <dd style="display: none"><ul><li><a href="#chapter_toc1558" id="chapter1558">Chapter I - Palace of Twilight</a></li>
           <li><a href="#chapter_toc1611" id="chapter1611">Chapter II - Of Worlds Left Behind</a></li></ul></dd>
```

Comment: Right now my li is a child of ul.... it's right after the dd. But would that cause my click-on thing to not work?

Comment: Probably not; but my apologies, I hadn't seen the `<ul>` tags.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show any `showHide` function.  All you need to do is create it.  It could look something like this:

```
<script>
    function showHide(actElement) {
        var current = actElement.firstChild.style.display;
        if (current == "none") {
            actElement.firstChild.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            actElement.firstChild.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

There are shorter ways to write this, that have the same functionality, e.g.:

```
<script>
    function showHide(actElement) {
        actElement.firstChild.style.display = (actElement.firstChild.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }
</script>
```

This does exactly the same, but in a more concise manner.

Comment: of course bear in mind that your teacher will probably know you didn't write the code if you use a ternary operator like in the second example here despite having no experience with coding ;)

Comment: Where would I put this?  Do I need to have it in my HTML (and if so, where? In the head, under the part it will work with?) or do I have to associate it?  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Ennui brings up a good point - your teacher can't expect you to know javascript without having taught you the basics.  The easiest answer is to put it in `<head>` of the HTML, though as you learn more, you'll find you can put things in the body, and/or save it as an external file.